# Perfomance impact using long values for SQL index

Tags: sql, mysql, indexing, database-performance, sqlperformance

For example: I have the table -

table User (id (bigint(20) primary key,  session_id (bigint(20), key(varchar(24) )

There is a unique index in that table including both session_id(bigint(20)) and key(varchar(24) ) columns.

Can there be a performance impact to system if I will change 'key' column to varchar(255) (use long values for this column) , since it is a part of a unique index?

I'm using Mysql database(AWS Aurora).

Comment: i think hat the impact will be not that massive, but try it your self

Answer (score 1):

Short Answer:  No significant performance impact.

Long Answer:

- The `PRIMARY KEY` is a `UNIQUE` index; both are `INDEXes`.  (That is, do not make redundant indexes.)
- The impact of a `VARCUAR` in an index is mostly based on the *average* length of the actual strings.  The *max* length does not matter (unless it hits some limit, such as 3072 *bytes*).
- The number of rows touched is the biggest factor in performance.  Indexes help minimize that.